# Как оформить дословные высказывания с восклицательным знаком и местоимением?

Tags: вводные-слова, прямая-речь, бессоюзное

Два предложения на эту тему:

(1) *Я... отказалась от этой мысли. Но я еще к ней вернусь! – **так подумала я**.*

(2) *Богоматерь Студеницкая! – **вот первая из более или менее чётких мыслей**, которая возникла теперь в моей голове.*

Местоимение и частица мешают оформлению по образцу прямой речи. БСП? Вводное предложение? А что делать с восклицательным знаком, он же в середине предложения не ставится.

Comment: Во втором случае всё ясно: перед тире правильно использовать кавычки, а после идёт комментарий этой как бы цитаты. Я часто так оформляю текст, комментируя чей-то ответ. В первом - прямая речь. Не понимаю, что там и как мешает.

Comment: Ну да, мне тут только кавычек и не хватает. Типичное БСП, там даже запятую можно поставить: Я еще вернусь, так подумала я. А если вы кавычки будете ставить, то слова автора разве могут начинаться с местоимения. Тогда было бы: "Я еще вернусь!" - подумала я.

Comment: "*Так подумала я*" - звучит как комментирование цитаты. Плохо оформлять без кавычек. Или чуть поменять: *Я еще вернусь, как мне кажется.* Думаю, что "*так*" в начале вполне допустимо, если оно выражает не примерность (*как-то так*), а точность (*вот так*).

Comment: Всё уж оформлено и исправлению не подлежит.  Мешает только восклицательный знак. Поэтому меня интересует только правомерность его употребления.

Comment: Увы, не ставят восклицательный/вопросительный знак в середине. Предложение - это мысль, интонация у него должна быть единой (одной из трёх). Если мысль внутри мысли - то это цитата.

Comment: Может, и не ставят, а мне надо поставить. Должны быть исключения, просто вы не хотите их найти.

Comment: Как найти то, чего нет?)))

Comment: Это уже ваши трудности. Исключения есть всегда. Мне что, из-за восклицательной интонации менять оформление предложения, портить весь текст? Это нелогично.

Comment: Можно просто поставить кавычки.

Comment: Это будут первые кавычки в этой главе, причем совершенно неуместные. В общем, когда найдете пример или правило, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом. Спасибо.